# mySQL not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, database

I am running the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE (post_title LIKE 'Professionally') 
OR (post_content LIKE 'Professionally') 
AND post_type='post' 
AND post_status='publish'
```

I know that I have a row that has `post_type` of `post`, and `post_status` of `publish` that starts with the word 'Professionally' (copied and pasted from phpmyadmin) but this query returns no results.

Oddly, when the query successfully matches a `popst_title` it works as expected.

Comment: You are not using any wildcards. For a "begins with" search you need to add `%` e.g. `Professionally%`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html), you use a `%` in order to do substring matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE (post_title LIKE 'Professionally%'
    OR post_content LIKE 'Professionally%')
    AND post_type = 'post'
    AND post_status = 'publish'
```

*(I also modified your bracketing to better express what I think you are trying to do.)*

Comment: Also worth noting: `OR` has lower precendence than `AND`, meaning the query will match any post which `post_title` starts with `'Professionally'`, regardless of its type and status, and only the ones typed `'post'` with status of `'publish'` and having a content starting with `'Professionally'`. From the SQL and question, seems to me this is not the intended behavior...